# gulp task to prepend html code into existing html pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gulp

I am facing a problem in writing a gulp task which basically prepend small HTML code into all the existing html files in the application.
so my existing html looks like

```
<div class="input-field-group">
    <span class="error-validation">
        <small class="inline-error">
            <span>This field is required</span>
        </small>
        <small class="inline-error">
            <span>This field is required</span>
        </small>
        <small class="inline-error">
            <span>This field is required</span>
        </small>
    </span>
</div>
```

this is same across multiple html files in entire application. What I want to prepend is one more span element just above error message in all the html files across the application. something like this:

```
<div class="input-field-group">
    <span class="error-validation">
        <small class="inline-error">
            ***<span aria-hidden="true" class="error-icon"></span>***
            <span>This field is required</span>
        </small>
        <small class="inline-error">
            ***<span aria-hidden="true" class="error-icon"></span>***
            <span>This field is required</span>
        </small>
        <small class="inline-error">
            ***<span aria-hidden="true" class="error-icon"></span>***
            <span>This field is required</span>
        </small>
    </span>
</div>
```

I have started writing down the gulp task but kind of lost in between. I am using gulp-dom plugin.

```
 var gulp = require('gulp');
 var dom = require('gulp-dom');
 gulp.task('prepend-html', function(){
     return gulp.src('./**/*.html')
         .pipe(dom(function(){
             var divLengths = this.querySelectorAll('small').length;
             var parentDiv = this.querySelector('small');
             for(var i = 0; i < divLengths; i++) {
                 var childSpan = this.createElement('span');
                 childSpan.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
                 childSpan.setAttribute('class', 'error-icon');
                 parentDiv.insertBefore(childSpan, parentDiv.firstChild);
                 return this;
             }
         }))
         .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file){
               return file.base;
     }));
 });
```

I know I kind of made a mess inside the loop. it is working but not as expected. It should go to each folder and each file and look for small element and then prepend span element. Any kind of help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing operation on single span only in for loop. Following will work -

```
     var gulp = require('gulp');
     var dom = require('gulp-dom');
     gulp.task('default', function(){
         return gulp.src('./**/*.html')
             .pipe(dom(function(){
                 var divLengths = this.querySelectorAll('small').length;
                 var parentDiv = this.querySelectorAll('small');
                 for(var i = 0; i < divLengths; i++) {
                     console.log(i);
                     var childSpan = this.createElement('span');
                     childSpan.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
                     childSpan.setAttribute('class', 'error-icon');
                     parentDiv[i].insertBefore(childSpan, parentDiv[i].firstChild);
                 }
                 return this;
             }))
             .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file){
                   return file.base;
         }));
     });
```